# How to delete Nodes in linked list with zero value in c

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm using codeBlock and i'm trying to delete all the nodes with zero value
at first i deleted the head nodes until there is no zero  value in head 
like that

```
void exo6(Node* head)
{
    Node* p=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p=head;
    head=p;
    if(p->data==0)
    {
        while(p->data==0)
        {
            head=p->next;
            free(p);
            p=head;
        }
    }
    head=p;
```

Then i continue to delete the next nodes like that

```
while(p!=null)
    {
        if(p->next->data==0)
        {
            Node* q=p->next;
            free(p->next);
            p->next=q->next;
        }else
            p=p->next;

    }
    printf("The NEw list is \n");
    display(head);

}
```

but the code worked only on the head nodes

the result is like this [image: the final result of code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is when the function accepts the pointer to the head node by reference.

Here you are.

```
void exo6( Node **head )
{
    while ( *head != NULL )
    {
        if ( ( *head )->data == 0 )
        {
            Node *current = *head;
            *head = ( *head )->next;
            free( current );
        }
        else
        {
            head = &( *head )->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Call the function like

```
exo6( &head )l
```

As for your function implementation then it starts from a memory leak

```
void exo6(Node* head)
{
    Node* p=(Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p=head;
    // ...
```

At first memory is allocated and its address is stored in the pointer `p` and then at once the pointer is reassigned. Also take into account that in general the function can be called when the pointer to the head node is equal to NULL.
Moreover the function accepts the pointer to the head node by value. So the function deals with a copy of the original pointer. Changing the copy does not influence on the original pointer.